# StackTracker - Cross-platform desktop notification app

Tags: app, python, notifier, qt

[image]

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Current Version: Beta build v1.0

[image]
[image]

### About

StackTracker, a cross-platform desktop notifier for the StackExchange API built with PyQt4

The application displays a task tray notification when someone has posted an answer or a comment to a question you
are tracking on any of the StackExchange sites.  Clicking the notification will open the corresponding question in your browser.

#### License

GPL - Full LICENSE file available in the repo (below)

#### Download

Linux build:  [Download Linux ZIP](http://github.com/swanson/stacktracker/archives/v1.0) (Requires Python 2.6 and PyQt4 to be installed)

Run `>> python StackTracker.py` from the StackTracker folder

---

Windows build: [Download Windows ZIP](http://github.com/downloads/swanson/stacktracker/StackTracker%20v1.0.zip) (May need Microsoft VC++ DLL installed)

Launch the `StackTracker.exe`.

---

Mac OS X build: [Download Mac OS X tarball](http://github.com/downloads/swanson/stacktracker/StackTracker%20v1.0%20-%20OS%20X.tar.gz) (Requires Growl to be installed)

Launch `StackTracker.app`. Only tested in Leopard/Snow Leopard on Intel-based Macs.

### Contact

Matt Swanson, mdswanso@purdue.edu

### Code

Tools/Frameworks/Etc Used: Python, PyQt4, gVim

Repo: `git clone git@github.com:swanson/stacktracker.git`

http://github.com/swanson/stacktracker

### Release Notes

Please post feature requests or bugs in the answer section.  Patches or pull requests are more than welcome.

#### Beta Builds

**v1.0** (July 9)

- StackTracker has now entered Beta status!
- Support for API v1.0 release
- Fixed bug in Mac OS X build involving exiting from the tray icon
- Added Mac OS X build icon
- Added default logo for all new Area51/StackExchange sites
- Economized API calls
- Added better handling of multiple alerts overwriting each other
- Added notification when a question is autoremoved
- Removed option to autoremove on accept answers
- Code clean-up and refactoring

#### Alpha Builds

**v0.4.1** (June 24)

- Updating app to API version 0.9

**v0.4** (June 23)

- Fixed bug with gzipped API response that broke
  nearly all functionality :)
- Added Mac OS X build

**v0.3** (June 8)

- Major UI changes
- Windows build released and tested
- Added settings for auto-removing questions
  and changing update interval
- Shifted application design from a single window
  to a system tray icon
- Added answer count and asked by fields to question list
- Clicking on a question title in the window will now open
  the question in the browser
- Throttling API calls to adhere to new "conscientious use" policy
- Changed application icon
- Adding error dialogs for bad input to question URL field
- Added support for Python 2.5 JSON library
- Fixed bug related to local time vs GMT
- Fixed bug where the same question could be tracked multiple times
- Code clean-up and refactoring

**v0.2** (May 28)

- Added support for other 'Trilogy'
  sites
- Questions in the list are colored
  based on which site they are from
- Changed input from question ID to
  question URL
- Fixed Segmentation Fault when closing
  program
- Fixed bug where invalid system clock
  could cause multiple notifications
  for same answer/comment
- Various refactoring and code clean-up

**v0.1** (May 26)

- Initial build

Comment: WHOAH! That's a good idea! Maybe I'll check you GIT out, to put a SuperUser version!

Comment: Amazing job. One feature you may want to incorporate down the road is auto-expiry for watches. That way, after say 8 hours, I am no longer informed of new data for a question and my list is less-cluttered. Just a thought.

Comment: @George Ya I am debating whether to do that or some kind of exponential backoff in the query time.  My current plan is to add it as a user setting - 'Should questions auto-expire? After how long?'.  It will likely come in v0.3 as I will be adding persistence of tracked questions.

Comment: Has anyone tried the Windows EXE? Is it working for you? I've tested it on a few computers at my home so let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Any plan to release an OSX build :P?

Comment: Ya, actually I have been trying to build PyQt on OSX all week -- I will try to get an OSX build out at some point.

Comment: @systempuntoout I added an OS X build, let me know if you have any problems - it seemed to work fine on the two Macs I tested it on.

Comment: @swanson cool, i'm going to try it this evening..thanks.

Comment: The app is now API v0.9 complaint.  Version < 0.4.1 will no longer work as API v0.8 has been killed.

Comment: Ya I didnt realize the Windows and OS X had different icon files -- Ill be sure to be add that in the next release. thanks for testing it out for me!

Comment: Is there support for notifications on new questions matching a tag?

Comment: Where is Linux build?

Comment: Hello @swanson when I copy the URL concerned the webpage of a question, I got the error: invalid URL format, please try again. How can I overcome this problem? I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

I've got some problem using ST under Ubuntu 10.04.

This is what I get when I launch

`>> python StackTracker.py`:

[image]

This is the window while I enter the URL:

[image]

And this is the window after the URL to be tracked is submitted:

[image: image really was repeated]

Any thought and/or advice for the troubleshoot?

**EDIT: Version 0.4 works! YAY!!!**

[image]

Comment: Could you give me the full URL that you tried? If the app didnt crash in a blaze of fire, it's probably thinks that the URL is invalid (there is 'error checking' with a simple regex).  Also what version are you running? The newest from github? The v0.3 tarball?

Comment: Actually the issue was the recent addition of gzipping the api response -- which doesn't play nicely with urllib2.urlopen.  I am working on a patch that should resolve the issue.

Comment: This has been fixed in v0.4.  Thank you very much for testing out the app and alerting me of the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to run this on openSUSE 11.2, getting an error message:

```
sathya@shaman:~/Download/stacktracker> python StackTracker.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StackTracker.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit, QtNetwork
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v6.0 but the PyQt4.QtCore module requires API v7.
```

Comment: Does updating your `sip` module solve the problem?  I haven't gotten around to making a standalone Linux install so you may need to update that module for it to run at the moment.

Comment: This is apparently a common problem with openSUSE and some other distros (gentoo) - an example: http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2010-04/msg00293.html

Answer (score 1):

This leaks memory. After running it for 24h, it was using >400 MB