# Message Notification App for AskUbuntu and/or StackExchange

Tags: support, app-request, notifier, systemtray

I was wondering if there is any way to get notified in due time when someone replies to my posts/comments on AskUbuntu.com or StackExchange.com, other than via email notifications.

What I have in mind is some light application that can be used inside Linux/Ubuntu, and maybe inside Windows, something close to instant messaging clients, which can reside in system tray, named **AskUbuntu notification daemon** or **StackExchange messenger** or so.

I have read about a few similar projects in here but they all need to be integrated into a web browser, and frankly I do not surf the web all day long, there are times when I don't use a web browser for hours.

Comment: What about  stack exchange android app, it notifies if someone responds to your comment/ question etc?

Comment: I browsed for similar apps in here, and found the stack exchange android app but I can't use it, don't have the hardware for that :). But thanks to you, I did another search and found [this useful piece of software](http://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-cross-platform-desktop-notification-app) with support for Linux, Windows and Mac OS X. Already tested it inside Windows, and it does not need you to actually login to get notified but instead input one or more URLs of interest to you, and allow the app residing in system tray to notify your for new posts and comments for those URLs.

Comment: As far as I can tell, StackApplet does what you've described.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to find what I was looking for.

After doing some research in here, on [stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com), I have finally found what I was looking for, namely an easy way to get notified about new answers, posts and/or comments for the topics that I am interested in, topics listed on all sites from StackExchange network.

The application is called [StackTracker](https://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-cross-platform-desktop-notification-app) (a Cross-platform desktop notification app) and it has support for Windows and Mac OS X. I am not sure about Linux, I tried to find a link for the Linux version but I seem to be getting nowhere. So, I just use StackTracker in Linux via Wine software.